# How can Apache Kafka send messages to multiple consumer groups?

Tags: apache-kafka

In the [Kafka documentation](http://kafka.apache.org/documentation.html#theconsumer):

> Kafka handles this differently. Our topic is divided into a set of
>   totally ordered partitions, each of which is consumed by one consumer
>   at any given time. This means that the position of consumer in each
>   partition is just a single integer, the offset of the next message to
>   consume. This makes the state about what has been consumed very small,
>   just one number for each partition. This state can be periodically
>   checkpointed. This makes the equivalent of message acknowledgements
>   very cheap.

Yet, following their quick start guide in that same document, I was easily able to:

1. Create a topic with a single partition
2. Start a console-producer
3. Push a few messages
4. Start a consumer to consume `--from-beginning`
5. Start **another** consumer `--from-beginning`

And have both consumers successfully consume from the same partition.

But this seems at odds with the documentation above?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When using different consumer groups, consumers can consume the same partitions easily. You may consider group ids as different applications consuming a Kafka topic. Multiple different applications might want to use the data in a Kafka topic differently and thus not to conflict with other applications. That's why two consumers may consume one partition (in fact the only way how two consumers can consume one partition).

And when you start a console consumer it randomly generates a group id for it ([link](https://github.com/apache/kafka/blob/0.8.2/core/src/main/scala/kafka/tools/ConsoleConsumer.scala#L124)) thus these consumers are doing exactly what I just wrote.

Comment: I agree that this is useful and desired. Perhaps the documentation could be clarified from "is divided into a set of totally ordered partitions, each of which is consumed by one consumer at any given time" -> "is divided into a set of totally ordered partitions, each of which is consumed by one consumer *in each consumer group* at any given time" Is that correct?

Comment: Also, who is responsible for storing the offset index? The consumer? What about when it is checkpointed?

Comment: @JKnight, yes for the first question. The offsets are stored in "offset storage" which in most cases is Zookeeper. The other option is to store offsets in Kafka, but this feature was added recently and I doubt folks use it that much. Commit offset has some settings, like `autocommit.enable` and `autocommit.interval.ms`. When autocommit is enabled offsets for all partitions will be commited every interval mentioned before. If you turn off the autocommit you'll be forced to call `commitOffsets()` periodically or store them somewhere else away from Kafka/Zookeeper.

Comment: @serejja - so if you do have two different consumer groups reading from the same partition, and both call commitOffsets() with different values of offset - are they maintained/stored as separate offset values for each consumer group fro this partition? thanks!

Comment: @JKnight, yes, that's the point of consumer groups - you may have different groups have different offsets checkpointed. They are stored in zookeeper in `consumers/<groupid>/offsets/<topic>/<partitions>` nodes and thus won't conflict with each other